# Error while using Markdown with Django

Tags: python, django, markdown

From commandline, I'm using this to convert a string to html:

```python
    >>>import markdown
    >>> mk = Markdown()
    >>> html = mk.convert(my_string)
```

and it gets me the html string without any errors, however when using the same in a module the django page prints an error as 'Global name 'markdown' not defined'

I cleared this out by using

```python
    import markdown
    mk = markdown.Markdown()
    html = mk.convert(my_string)
```

I'm a newbie and I need to know why the code which runs in the interpreter mode gives error when put inside a module. Does this mean  whatever I try without errors in interpreter mode may probably bring error when wrote as code? Help

Comment: This is the error I'm getting: 
>>> import markdown
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named markdown

Answer (score 3):

That code as shown would *not* work in the interpreter. You must have previously run `from markdown import Markdown`,  or `from markdown import *`.

Answer (score 2):

Simply run:

```
import markdown

html = markdown.markdown(my_string)
```

If this does not work, it would help for us to see the actual error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

The django docs weren't very clear about the fact you'd need to actually install something else to get this up. The only thing included by default from Django is the markup app to use markdown in templates, not in models.

Use the documentation here to install markdown and use this syntax:

http://packages.python.org/Markdown/reference.html

or

`pip install markdown`

or

`easy_install markdown`

Answer (score 1):

Spent so many hours on this. Just do the following command, works for python3.6 and Django 2.0.5+ version.

`pip install django-markdown-deux`

Answer (score 0):

Solution suggested by Akansha worked to fix a similar problem

```
 pip install django-markdown-deux
```